# php - download a cookie together with pdf

Tags: php, cookies

I need to download a cookie together with PDF. I added setcookie to following function but it doesn't work. What's wrong? Thanks

```
protected function send_download($file) {
    if (file_exists($file)) {
        set_time_limit(0);
        header('Connection: Keep-Alive');
        header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
        header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($file).'"');
        setcookie("fileDownloadToken", "fileDownloadToken", time()+360); // 10 minutes
        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
        header('Pragma: public');
        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
        ob_clean();
        flush();
        readfile($file);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Resolved :)
It was visible only as response cookie. It was necessary to set path and domain.

```
            setcookie("fileDownloadToken", $fileDownloadToken, time()+360, '/', $this->template->domain); // 10 minutes
```